# Displaying number before decimal points in oracle

Tags: oracle, computed-column, decimal

I have a logic where I want to calculate and display numbers based upon some operations. The operations are below

`V_CALPERCENT nvarhcar(100)`, `v_yearMSA1 nvarchar(100)`,

So I want to calculate `V_CALPERCENT` and I have one value for `v_yearMSA1 = 2`

SO here goes my calculation,

```
V_CALPERCENT :=  (v_yearMSA1  * 2.25) / 100
```

Its returning me as `.05`

where as I want it should also display the number before decimal point. How to get it please help

Comment: The client software is typically responsible for formatting query output; so, what client are we talking about?

Comment: @mustaccio: but the same I am trying using dual is giving me the expected format. What do you mean by client software ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942113/exact-difference-between-oracle-client-and-oracle-database

Comment: mine oracle is `18.3.0`

Comment: `select (2 * 2.5) / 100 from dual` is giving me proper output as `0.05` why ?

Comment: How can you "calculate V_CALPERCENT" when V_CALPERCENT is a character string, not a NUMBER.  This is going to require implicit to_num and to_char operations.  Use the correct data types.

Comment: Why do you store **numeric** values in `nvarchar(100)` data type - it's almost the worst you can do.

Comment: A number is a number. What you show is the result of the default sqlplus formatting. In real life, applications are written in a variety of languages (C, C++, Python, Java ...) and the formatting is managed entirely by the functions provided in the language you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
SQL> select to_char((2 * 2.5) / 100) from dual;

TO_
---
.05

SQL> select to_char((2 * 2.5) / 100, '99990D99') from dual;

TO_CHAR((
---------
     0.05

SQL>
```

Update:

Number example:

```
SQL> select (2 * 2.5) / 100 as mynum from dual;

     MYNUM
----------
       .05

SQL> col mynum format 99990D99
SQL> select (2 * 2.5) / 100 as mynum from dual;

    MYNUM
---------
     0.05

SQL>
```

[Number Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Format-Models.html#GUID-291CA766-0B7D-4336-954A-B8A23036F6ED)

Comment: so you mean to say, I need to use `to_char` for that ?

Comment: @hud No. I mean to say that you need to format the output with the required format string if you want to store it in a character type. Which you should not do anyway. Having `v_yearMSA1` and `V_CALPERCENT` as char types - that is a huge red flag, this is poor quality code. Numbers should be stored in number types and formatting the output is the clients responsibility.

Comment: So, shall I take the datatype as number, I tried it with that too but I was not getting any values before decimal.. WHY ?

Comment: @hud Because you did not set the proper display format. I added an example.

Comment: Thanks Balazs, your explanation cleared my most of the doubts..